# Servlet doPost method

Tags: java, servlets

This is a simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
            <title>GET_POST</title>
    </head>
    <body>

       <h5> Insert username and password  </h5>

       <form action ="./get_Post" method ="post">
           username: <br>
           <input type = "text" name = "username">
           <br>
           password:<br>
           <input type = "password" name ="password">
           <br><br>
           <input type = "submit" value = "LOGIN">
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The form of this html page called the servlet has */get_Post* as url-mapping in web.xml.

Now, this is doPost method of the servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(password);
}
```

I expected null pointer exception, and instead the servlet gets the password I put in the html form. What can I do to make private password information?

Comment: What do you mean by private information? At some point you should pass password to your server side to do a validation. Instead you would use SSL to prevent theft of password while transmitting.

Comment: The server has to receive the password data if you expect it to authenticate. If you're worried about it being sent in plain text, use an `https` protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about security you need to enable SSL. For tomcat; first create a keystore and then add an SSL connector description to `server.xml`

```
<Connector port="8443" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
   keystoreFile="somekeystore" sslProtocol="TLS"
   keystorePass="pwd" />
```

Then forward login requests to HTTPS page and redirect to HTTP after authorization.